# GridView Docking Issue

Tags: winforms, layout, datagridview, anchor

I have a gridview and textbox control in my form. Textbox is on left top and under gridview anchored left, right and bottom. I want it saves the distance with textbox above it. This is my code below and it doesn't save the distance between textbox. when i make the window full screen there are so much distance between them as image.

```
dataGridView1.Anchor = (AnchorStyles.Left | AnchorStyles.Right | AnchorStyles.Bottom);
```

[image]

Comment: Anchor it to the Top as well

Comment: It covers the the textbox in that case. I want its to be right under the textbox @Saragis

Comment: How is your textbox Anchored? If it's Top & Left it'll work. Anchoring a control means that the anchored edges remain in the same position relative to the edges of the parent control.

Comment: I havent anchored my textbox anywhere, let me try it

Comment: Awesome, that fixed my problem, thank you @Saragis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this is what you need

```
  private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
  //just setting panel color to red. so you can see the panel.
 var panel = new Panel() {  BackColor= Color.Red};
            this.Controls.Add(panel);
            panel.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
            var textBox = new TextBox() {  Top = 20, Left = 20, Height=10, Width=330};
            panel.Controls.Add(textBox);

            var dataGridView = new DataGridView() ;

            dataGridView.Columns.Add("Name","Text");
            this.Controls.Add(dataGridView);
            dataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
            dataGridView.DataSource = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).ToList();
            dataGridView.BringToFront();
            dataGridView.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
}
```